# Upgrade ERC721 Contract

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

I've a question about an upgrade that I should apply to a contract that I deployed as upgradable (with openzeppelin Upgradable).

I'm following the guidelines and best practices but I'm not sure the change I'd like to apply would have any issue.

I would like to:

1. create a new contract V2 starting from the deployed one
2. add on this contract a new bool variable

`bool private isLocked;`

(as last variable in the variables list declaration and without a starting value, since the initialize has been called with the proxy contract deployment)

The first contract deployed has this function:

```
 function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override (ERC721Upgradeable,ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable) {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
  }
```

I would change it this way, to let the transfer only when isLocked is false or the users are minting

```
 function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override (ERC721Upgradeable,ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable) {
        require(!isLocked || from == address(0));
        
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

And then adding set and get methods to change and retrieve the isLocked variable.

Then I would deploy using the original contract address as in the documentation

```
async function main () {
  const ContractV2 = await ethers.getContractFactory('ContractV2');
  console.log('Upgrading ContractV2...');
  await upgrades.upgradeProxy(FIRST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ContractV2);
  console.log('Contract upgraded');
}

main();
```

Just as "code review" since it would have an impact on an already deployed contract, do you see any issue with these changes?

The new functions, for example the get and set of the "isLocked" variable, need to follow a specific order in the code (for example at the end of the contract code) or can be placed anywhere, any other aspect to consider?

Thank you